# No property or field exists in type dynamic class

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, predicate, anonymous

I am trying to create a dynamic query for my reports.
my query returns IEnumerable that uses `.select(selectstringquery)` and `.where(wherestringquery).` The select and where strings vary on diff cases base on what and when I need it.

```
string   selectstringquery = "student_fname, student_lname"
string wherestringquery = "student_lname='joe'";

var test = (from s in students).select(selectstringquery).where(wherestringquery); //this works well

wherestringquery = "student_isRegistered=false";
var test = (from s in students).select(selectstringquery).where(wherestringquery) //this fails coz isRegistered is a valid proerpty but not is NOT in select query.
```

> It throws an error No property or field 'student_isRegistered' exists
>   in type '<>f__AnonymousType337`14'

But if it works when I put the where inside the linq

ex.

```
 (from s in students
where s_isRegistered=false).select(selectstringquery)
```

How can I make it work without having to include the column in the select query? reason is I want to reuse the query in all reports and some don't need that filter.

Also, in this case, I am using

"if else "
 to determine if wherestringquery is not empty, else I use an exactly the same query like above but without the **.where(wherestringquery)**. Is there a possible way to use **.where() even if the wherestringquery is empty**? I tried writing .where(true) but it throws exception.

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to add where before select?, Something `var test = (from s in students).where(wherestringquery).select(selectstringquery)`

Comment: okay. this works. :) how about the dynamic where? Is there any other way to use only 1 query but the where string is sometimes empty?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that, one hack is that you can always have a where statement, e.g. 1=1. There is no harm in using if else as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to apply where clause after selecting fewer columns via select clause. Just do the where before selecting columns e.g.

```
var test = (from s in students).where(wherestringquery).select(selectstringquery);
```